# IPV6 Binding Failure Error: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, bind, ipv6

1. I  have configured Ubuntu Linux system with the following interfaces & assigned IPV6 addresses as follows:

   **Eth0**:      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:8d:57:64
                  inet addr:192.168.254.10  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
                  inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:5764/64 Scope:Link
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:74231424 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:400372550 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
             RX bytes:24514286488 (24.5 GB)  TX bytes:115992171490 (115.9 GB)

   **Eth1**:     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:8d:7c:4c
             inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
             inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:7c4c/64 Scope:Link
             inet6 addr: fc00:1234:1::10/120 Scope:Global
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:434933479 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:39666183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
             RX bytes:126065364448 (126.0 GB)  TX bytes:14437801257 (14.4 GB)

   **Eth2**:     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:8d:56:14
             inet addr:192.168.2.10  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
             inet6 addr: fc00:1234:2::10/120 Scope:Global
             inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:5614/64 Scope:Link
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:480068741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:34145702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
             RX bytes:146795537550 (146.7 GB)  TX bytes:10045338657 (10.0 GB)
2. I wanted to do Socket programming using IPV6 sockets. The code snippet that I have written is as follows:

   struct sockaddr_in6 sin
   Ipv6_fdr = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)

   bzero(&sin, sizeof(sin));
   sin.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
   sin.sin6_port = htons(2152);
         if ((setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(int))) < 0)
   memcpy(&(sin.sin6_addr), "fc00:1234:1::10",sizeof(sin.sin6_addr));
         if ((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin)))< 0)
3. After successful compilation, I’m getting IPV6 bind failure Error with the following error number & name:
   **EADDRNOTAVAIL   99  /* Cannot assign requested address**.
   After certain number of attempts for IPV6 Binding it throws Segmentation Fault error.

It would be great if someone could help me on what mistake I’m doing here & why IPV6 binding is failing?

Comment: FYI, the address, `fc00:1234:1::10`, is in a reserved range that you are not allowed to use. ULA addressing is in the `fc00::/7` range, but the `fc00::/8` half of the range is reserved for a yet-to-be-named global authority to assign. The `fd00::/8` half of the range is open for local assignment, but you _MUST_ use a random number generator to assign the next 40 bits in the address. You also seem to have a problem that you are not using `/64` as the network size. Many things in IPv6 can fail if you use a different network size. With only a couple of exceptions, you should use `/64` networks.

Comment: @RonMaupin I tried changing my IPV6 address with a /64 network size as suggested by you. Also, I tried different inet6 addresses of various prefixes & different network configurations ranges. Still the same problem persists on running the script. IPV6 Bind failure: Cannot assign requested address. Kindly help me on the same.

Comment: I wasn't trying to solve the problem in your question. I was trying to guide you to proper IPv6 addressing, which I don't believe is your posted problem, but it could pose a different set of problems if you fix your current problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is the line:

```
memcpy(&(sin.sin6_addr), "fc00:1234:1::10",sizeof(sin.sin6_addr));
```

It is necessary to convert the human readable string to binary and store the binary form of address to sin6_addr like:

```
inet_pton (AF_INET6, "fc00:1234:1::10", sin.sin6_addr.s6_addr);
```